# Can a XAML object be a source for one binding as well as a target for another binding?

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

Is it possible to have a TextBlock as a target and a source?

Basically I have a bunch of entities which have simple relationships to other entities (like Entity1 Knows Entity3, Entity3 WorksAt Entity2 etc.)

I have a `Link` class that stores `SourceEntity`, `Relationship` and `TargetEntity` details.

What I want to be able to do is to select an entity then display the relationships related to that entity, with the target entities of each relationship listed underneath the relationship names.

When an entity is selected, an `ObservableCollection` is populated with the `Links` for that particular entity (`SelectedEntityLinks<Link>`).

Because each entity could have the same relationship to more than one target entity (Entity1 could know both Entity3 and Entity4 for eg.), I've created a method `GetThisRelationshipEntities()` that takes a relationship name as a parameter, looks through `SelectedEntityLinks` for relationship names that match the parameter, and returns an `ObservableCollection` with the target entities of that relationship.

In my xaml I have a `WrapPanel` to display each relationship name in a TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="relationship" Text="{Binding Path=Relationship.Name}" />
```

Then underneath that another Textblock which should display the results of `GetThisRelationshipEntities(String relationshipName).`

So I want the "relationship" TextBlock to both get its Text from the binding I've shown above, but also to provide its Text as a parameter to the `GetThisRelationshipEntities()` method which I've added to `<UserControl.Resources>` as an ObjectDataProvider.

Sorry if this is a bit wordy but I hope it's clear. Any pointers/advice would be great.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you should create a value converter class using IValueConverter and a property which is you relations table.
When doing

```
<TextBlock x:Name="relationship" Text="{Binding Path=Relationship.Name}" />
```

you would add

```
<TextBlock x:Name="relationship" Text="{Binding Path=Relationship.Name, Converter={StaticResource myRelationConverter}}" />
```

in the `Convert()` method you can do any crazy thing you want to.

Comment: Thanks Martin, I'll look into Value Converters. One question though, if I'm using a method called Convert(), how do I pass it the Relationship.Name from the TextBlock? Or is that what using Converter={StaticResource myRelationConverter} would do? The Relationship.Name that the TextBlock is currently displaying is key to displaying the correct data. If only I could figure out how to retrieve it!

Comment: The converter is called as part of the binding operation. 1. The value of Relationship.Name is retrieved 2. the value is passed by the framework to the given value converters convert method 3. the Convert methods return value is written to the Text property

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure i got what you're trying to do, but i suggest trying to set the binding mode to TwoWay.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="relationship" Text="{Binding Path=Relationship.Name}"
             Mode=TwoWay />
```

although now that i think about it, it might be the default option, so you can also try to call the  GetThisRelationshipEntities() function on the TextBlock, every time it's source is updated:

```
private void relationship_SourceUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
{
    //To DO: whatever update you wanna make
}
```

Comment: Thanks Notter, but as I understand it, TwoWay binding only works between one Target & its Source. I need the "relationship" TextBlock to use a particular source (Relationship.Name) to set its Text value, then once the value is set, to provide it to a different target (using something like Text="{Binding Path = MethodParameters[0]"..../>).

Comment: Hmm, well i got a bit confused now, but i think my suggestion to update the different target on the SourceUpdated event would be the most simple way

Comment: Hm well I've had a go at using the SourceUpdated but with no luck. I think the problem is that my source is an ObservableCollection and my TextBlock named "relationship" is just displaying one after another of the Relationship.Names (It's in a wrappanel so it's displaying them one after another in the template I've specified.) So the source isn't actually being updated, it's just the Text value in the TextBlock that's changing. I tried using TargetUpdated as well but no luck with that either :(

Answer (score 0):

Your wording is a litte inaccurate: it is not the `DependencyObjects` that are the source or target of a binding, but the *properties* of the `DependencyObjects`. A plain property can only be the source in a binding, but a `DependencyProperty` can act both as a source and as a target. For example in

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Name="txtName" />
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=txtName, Path=Text}" />
```

the `Text` property of the `TextBox` is the target of the binding to some `Name` property in the `DataContext`, and at the same time it is the source of the binding to the `Content` property of the `Label`. The parameter of a method call is not a property, therefore it cannot be source or target in a binding. In your case the simplest solution is probably to handle the `TextBlock.TextChanged` event and to call your method from there. Using a `ValueConverter` as suggested by Martin is also an option.

**Edit:** Here is a working example that demonstrates the approach using the `TextChanged` event. It writes the contents of the `TextBox` to the `Console` everytime you change something. To bind to the result of your method you could just let the event handler write its result to a property and then bind to that property.

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" TextChanged="textBox1_TextChanged" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.textBox1.Text);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've tried using a TextBox.TextChanged event (as can't find a TextChanged event for a TextBlock), but it doesn't fire when the text changes. I'm still trying Value Converters as an option as well, but my Convert class throws an exception every time it's called. At least I'm learning a lot about WPF in the process of trying to solve this...!

I understand about it being the properties of DependencyObjects that are bound, but where I'm getting stuck is in trying to use the process outlined on this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348824.aspx

Comment: I've added the method GetThisRelationshipEntities(String relationshipName) as a UserControl resource, but in order to bind a DependencyObject's property to the result of the method I have to of course pass in a String value to the method. But to use a TextBlock.Text value as the parameter, it looks like you have to do something like <TextBlock Binding Source="{StaticResource getThisRelationshipEntities}" Path="MethodParameters[0]" />

Comment: That was what I meant by my TextBlock.Text property needing to be both a target & a source, because it is a target with Text="{Binding Path=Relationship.Name" but also a "source" for the method parameter.

I'll keep trying the different things you suggested however & will let you know if I have any success. Apologies for all the comments but I couldn't post everything in one go!